# C++ CURL Json request to discord API for message posting

Tags: c++, rest, curl, libcurl, discord

I'm setting up a C++ library for the discord API, I'm encountering some issues, though.

I need to make a (protected, so httpS) request to discord, which i have managed to do in python without any issues.

```py
basic_auth_headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bot {TOKEN}",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

channel_id = 562636135428521986
send_url = f"https://discordapp.com/api/v6/channels/{channel_id}/messages"
data = {
  "content": "Hello, World!",
  "tts": False,
   "embed": {
     "title": "Hello, Embed!",
     "description": "This is an embedded message."
   }
}

response = requests.post(send_url, json=data, headers=basic_auth_headers)
```

This is going fine, it sends the message in the chat.

But then when i have to port it to C++ I have no clue where to start.

```cpp
            auto h = get_basic_header();
            h.push_back("Content-Type: application/json");
            json j = json(
                {
                    {"content", "Hello, World!"},
                    {"tts", false},
                    {"embed", {
                        {"title", "Hello, Embed!"},
                        {"description", "This is an embedded message."}
                        } 
                    }
                }
            );
            CURL* curl;
            CURLcode res;
            struct curl_slist* headers = NULL;
            for (auto& each : h){
                headers = curl_slist_append(headers, each.c_str());
            }
            curl = curl_easy_init();
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://google.com/");
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPPOST, 1);
            res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

            curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

        std::string get_channel_link(long id){
            return "https://discordapp.com/api/v6/channels/" + std::to_string(id) + "/messages";
        }

        std::list<std::string> get_basic_header() {
            return { "Authorization: Bot " + token };
        }
```

I would appreciate some help, thank you in advance.

EDIT:
Token is my bot token, can't share that.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking about. Your question isn't specific. What goes wrong when you run your code?

Comment: It doesn't actually make the proper request and I can't seem to figure out what it is. As of right now, it's not setting the data properly, how to set the Json? Key, value pairs, you know? @Jupiter

Comment: Basically, I just want to replicate the python request in C++

Comment: A guess: curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://google.com/"); sets the URL to google.com. Maybe this isn't correct. Also: Is the code sending a request to discord at all?

Comment: I had it before, I tried some setopts on stack overflow, I just decided to start over with the request before I posted the thread. I just don't know how to do the Json data, and how to do the POST

Comment: channel id's are 64bit and can easily overflow your `long`, use `std::string get_channel_link(uint64_t id){` instead

Comment: dont worry, i typedef'd discord_id as uint128_t or 64_t forgot which one

Answer (score 0):

cURL uses a call-back function to read/write the body of a message you're sending/receiving.

So, you (at least normally) call `curl_easy_setopt` with the `CURLOPT_READFUNCTION` parameter to set a reading function. You typically also want to call `curl_easy_setopt` passing the `CURLOPT_READDATA` parameter, to set the buffer you'll be sending. Once you've done that, cURL will call your function, passing it the address you set with `CURLOPT_READDATA`.

As an aside, cURL uses "read" and "write" to refer to the movement of data between your code and cURL itself. As a result, when you're sending packets (which most people think of as writing) it uses the read function, and when you're receiving packets (which most people think of as reading) it uses the write function.

Also note that since it's being called by cURL, your callback function will normally need to use "C" linkage, and be a free function or static member function.